# Working with files I/O for beginners

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, ofstream

Hi all I am working on a school beginners project using files I/O in C++,

This program consist of two parts:
1) reading and processing a student data file, and writing the results to a student report file
2) modifying part 1 to calculate some statistics and writing them to another file.
For this assignment, you will be reading one input file and writing out two other files.

Your program will be run using the referenced student data file.

**Part 1 Detail**

Read in the student data file. This 50 record file consists of a (8-digit numeric) student id, 8 assignment's points, midterm points, final points and lab exercise points. You must again follow the syllabus specifications for the determination of the letter grade, this time, processing 50 student grades. Extra credit points are not applicable for this assignment.  You will write the input student data and the results of the processing into a student report file that looks like the output shown below. In addition to the input student data, the report should contain the "total" of the assignment grades, the total and percent of all points achieved, and the letter grade.  You may assume that the input data file does not contain any errant data.

The file looks like the one below:
[The file that we need to read from is hyperlinked here](http://voyager.deanza.edu/~bentley/ass6data.html)

The student report output file should look like this:

**The Student Report Output File**

```
Student  --- Asignment Grades -- Ass Mid Fin LEx Total Pct Gr
-------- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --- --- --- --- ----- --- --
56049257 16 16 20 16 12 15 12 20 115  58 123  59   355  89 B+
97201934 19 15 13 19 16 12 13 18 113  72 101  55   341  85 B 
93589574 13 16 19 19 18 12  6 14 111  58 108  50   327  82 B 
85404010 17 19 19 19 19 10 17 19 129  70 102  58   359  90 A-
99608681 11 15 19 19 17 10 16 19 116  42 117  57   332  83 B 
84918110 11 20 18 17 12  8 12 19 109  46 122  31   308  77 C 
89307179 16 16 19 18 14 17 15 19 120  56 117  52   345  86 B 
09250373 15 15 18 18 11 18 17 19 120  44 106  51   321  80 B-
91909583 12 14 16 19 20 11 20 16 117  66  92  50   325  81 B- 
...
```

**Part 2 Detail**

Write a summary report file that contains the average total points and average percent for all students. Also, display the number of A's, B's, C's, D's and F's for the students. Your summary output file should look something like this:

```
The average total points = ???
The average percent total = ??
The number of A's = ??
The number of B's = ??
The number of C's = ??
The number of D's = ??
The number of F's = ??
```

**Additional requirements**

1. All files must be checked for a successful open. They should also be closed when you are finished with them.
2. Make sure you write the student id with a leading 0, if appropriate (i.e. the 8th id).
3. Add headings to your output report file. They should be aligned and correctly identify the column data.
4. Do not use global variables, except for constants, in your solution.

For part 1 How do I duplicate the file and format it to add the headings above it and the grades at the end of each file into the new duplicated file??

Any help in this matter would be appreciated
thanks in advance.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ read from file structure".  There are too many examples.

Comment: First of all: Neat formatting. But "Gimmy tha code plz" - questions are usually too broad for SO. Try yourself, then ask when you have a *specific* problem to ask about.

Comment: By the way, you should post your attempt and include a description of where you are having issues.  Compiler messages, linker messages and run-time messages should be posted verbatim as text not as screen snapshot.

Comment: Have you written any code yet? SO will not write your program for you, but we will be more than happy to help with any problems you have once you've written it yourself.

Comment: How would I duplicate the file and add the grade and the headings in a new file?? for part 1? Do I add all the numbers in the file in to variables ?

Answer (score 1):

Engineering is all about converting a large complex problem into many smaller, easy to solve, problems.

Here is how I would start.

1.) Open input file.

2.) Read one line from input file.

3.) Break the input string from one line into values.

4.) Close input file.

5.) Open output file.

6.) Write results to output file.

References:
[1.)File I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)
[2.)std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)
[3.)File I/O C](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/)
Now you're pretty much there. Take it one step at a time.

Comment: Have not learnt the string class yet will have to do without using it!(step 3)

Comment: Have you been able to read from a file yet?  Start there.

Comment: Added a link to "C style" file I/O.  If you're not using std::string, then you're code isn't really C++.

Comment: I am able to read the input file but could't read the leading 0 (zero) in line 8.... how do I do that??

Comment: Ok I got that part i need to use setfill('0') to read the leading 0